# Get Display Enum in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

How get a display/description enum in LINQ query?

For example

```
 var query = dbo.Records.AsQueryable()
              .Select(x => new
              {
                  Id = x.Id,
                  Care = new
                  {
                      x.StartDate,
                      x.ForwardedBy,
                  },
                  Prescriptions = x.Prescriptions.Select(p => new
                  {
                      p.Medicament,
                      p.IntervalUse //My Enum, how get Display name?
                  }),
              }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

This query is an exampleand I need to be `AsQueryable` to generate faster query in my database

Comment: Any reason you can't just keep it as the `enum` and get the display name in your view or in your form? That would, generally, be the preferred method.

Comment: What do you mean Display/description?  do you have [DisplayNameAttribute]s on your enum, or are you talking about the enum's name

Comment: @JoshK I'm return to json

Comment: @SamIam Yes, i use DisplayNameAttribute and i can get DisplayName value in Linq query

Comment: Can't you just do a tostring that should return the name of the that enum value as a string? p.IntervalUse.ToString()

Comment: @CharlesMcIntosh using ToString is not user friendly

Comment: @JoshK using ToString() is not user friendly, my enum have a OnceDaily property and my user using pt-br

Answer (score 1):

Since LINQ doesn't know about that extension method, you will have to enumerate first, then get the attribute using reflection.

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum value)
    {
        var attribute = (DisplayNameAttribute) value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .Where(a => a is DisplayNameAttribute)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return attribute != null ? attribute.DisplayName : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I can't test this right now, but you may try this and let us know if it works:

```
var query = dbo.Records.Include(x => x.Prescriptions).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Care = new
                {
                    x.StartDate,
                    x.ForwardedBy,
                },
                Prescriptions = x.Prescriptions.Select(p => new
                {
                    p.Medicament,
                    p.IntervalUse.GetDisplayName()
                }),
            });
```

Comment: How I use in LINQ query ?

Comment: You can't use it in a LINQ query unless you have already enumerated the `IQueryable` because there is no mapping in LINQ to Entities for this.

Comment: Wtf? why ef have enum support, if not have support a linq enum? :|

Comment: It has enum support, but it doesn't know anything about the attributes you have on the enum or enum values, so it cannot map the extension method I provided to SQL or whatever back end you are using.

Comment: Other solution Josh? I can generate my sql query for faster query, use ToList() or AsEnumerable is slow

Comment: See my edit above (adding `ToList` to the `Prescriptions` select), but I can't test it here and it may not work. If that doesn't work, I can update it to something else to try. (Note that you have to have my extension method code too).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `System.Reflection` libraries.

```
public static GetMyEnumDisplayName(MyEnumType value)
{
    var displayAttribute = value.GetType()
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .GetDeclaredField(result)
        .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute));

        if (displayAttribute != null)
        {
            var Name = ((DisplayAttribute)displayAttribute).Name;
        }
}
```

That's not supported in linq to entities, but you can instead make that a helper property in your view model.

Your first step is to select a view model instead of an anonymous object
the next step is to add a function in the setter

```
public string EnumDisplayValue { get { return GetMyEnumDisplayName(MyEnumValue); } }
```

Comment: How i use in linq query?

Comment: @user98498  make that code into a method and call that method from the linq query

Comment: @user98498 what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a bad idea to write an `enum` extension method if it's something you're going to need often :

```
public static string Describe(this Enum enumVal)
{
    var type = enumVal.GetType();
    var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return (attributes.Length > 0) ? ((DescriptionAttribute)(attributes[0])).Description : enumVal.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you do not go for the simplest way:

```
public enum IntervalUse
    {
        Hourly,
        Daily,
        Weekly
    }

    public static class EnumExt
    {
        public static string GetDescription(this IntervalUse item)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case IntervalUse.Hourly:
                    return "Hour by hour";
                case IntervalUse.Daily:
                    return "Day by day";
                case IntervalUse.Weekly:
                    return "Each week ...";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(item), item, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

then you can call in your query : `p.IntervalUse.GetDescription()`